# Parallelization of perl script

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, while-loop

I have a perl script I wish to parrallelise.

It is composed of a `while` loop with over 11000 lines inside of another `while` loop of 3400 lines, which makes it extremely slow.

```
open (FILE1, "File1.txt") or die "Can't open File1";
open (OUT, ">Outfile.txt");

while (<FILE1>)
{ 
 my @data=split (/ /, $_);
 my $RS=1;
 open (FILE2, "File2.txt") or die "Can't open File2";
 while (<FILE2>)
 { 
  my @value=split (/ /, $_);
  if ($data[$RS] == 1) {print OUT $value[1];$RS++;}
  elsif ($data[$RS] == 2) {print OUT $value[2];$RS++;}
  elsif ($data[$RS] == 0) {print OUT $value[3];$RS++;}
 }
 close FILE2;

}
```

I'm looking for a way to do the equivalent of qsub with every line of `File1` so I can send 3440 jobs. Any suggestions? I'd like to stay with perl if possible. I tried to insert this code inside of a bash script, but I don't really understand how to insert a language inside another one.

My `File1` contains a list of ID with information in column. Each column is then related to a single line in `File2`. I'd like to be able to run the second loop for multiple ID simultaneously instead of one after another.

```
File1
ID     RS_10    RS_15    RS_30
23     1        0        1
34     2        2        0
45     1        1        0
23     0        0        2
10     2        1        1


File2
RS_10 A B C
RS_15 D E F
RS_30 G H I
```

Comment: How something is best parallelized depends very much on your algorithm. Your code snippet does not show useful code (It won't run doing anything useful, won't compile under `strict`, and has bad style). Also, I don't know what `qsub` is. Could you elaborate a bit more what you are actually trying to do, to avoid an XY-problem? Maybe there is an algorithm for your task that is faster than the current *O(n·m)*.

Comment: The problem is that your solution is O(N^2). You could maybe load one of the files into a hash to make this O(N). Also, accessing a file from a hash will be faster than reading it from disk.

Comment: Do you really think that 3440 jobs fighting for a CPU core would perform well?

Comment: @amon I voluntarily didn't write my conditions in the second loop because they are already working. This is just a simplified version of my code.

Comment: My point is that you don't neccessarily want to parallelize your code. Actually, you want to speed up your script. Showing example data was very helpful. Is it correct that each line in File1 actually has 3441 columns? What will you do with your two tables, and what is the output? have you considered using an SQL database? I have too little information to provide qualified suggestions.

Comment: @amon File1 has exactly 3449 IDs and since File2 has over 11 000 lines, File1 has over 11 000 columns. Like I said, I'd like to get it to perl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first rule of optimization is not to do it too early (i.e. jumping to premature conclusions without profiling your code).

The second rule would probably refer to caching.

The `File2` of yours isn't very large. I'd say we load it into memory. This has the following advantages:

- We do our parsing once and only once.
- The file isn't obscenly large, so space isn't much of an issue.
- We can create a data structure that makes lookups very simple.

About that first point: You split each line over three thousand times. Those cycles could have been better spent.

About that third point: you seem to do an index conversion:

```
1 → 1, 2 → 2, 0 → 3
```

Instead of testing for all values with an if/elsif-switch (linear complexity), we could use an array that does this translation (constant time lookups):

```
my @conversion = (3, 1, 2);
...;
print OUT $value[$conversion[$data[$RS++]]];
```

If this index conversion is constant, we could do it once and only once when parsing `File2`. This would look like

```
use strict; use warnings;
use autodie; # automatic error handling

my @file2;
{
  open my $file2, "<", "File2.txt";
  while (<$file2>) {
    my (undef, @vals) = split;

    # do the reordering. This is equivalent to @vals = @vals[2, 0, 1];
    unshift @vals, pop @vals;

    push @file2, \@vals;
  }
}
```

Now we can move on to iterating through `File1`. Printing the corresponding entry from `File2` now looks like

```
open my $file1, "<", "File1.txt";
<$file1>; # remove header
while (<$file1>) {
  my ($id, @indices) = split;
  print $id, map $file2[$_][$indices[$_]], 0 .. $#indices;
  # but I guess you'd want some separator in between
  # If so, set the $, variable
}
```

This algorithm is still quadratic (the `map` is just a `for`-loop in disguise), but this should have a better constant factor. The output of above code given your example input is

```
23 A F G
34 B E I
45 A D I
23 C F H
10 B D G
```

(with `$, = " "; $\ = "\n"`).

#### Where to go from here

This last step (looping through File1) *could* be parallelized, but this is unlikely to help much: IO is slow, communication between threads is expensive (IPC even more so), and the output would be in random order. We could spawn a bunch of workers, and pass unparsed lines in a queue:

```
use threads; # should be 1st module to be loaded
use Thread::Queue;
use constant NUM_THREADS => 4; # number of cores

# parse the File2 data here

my $queue = Thread::Queue->new;
my @threads = map threads->new(\&worker), 1 .. NUM_THREADS;

# enqueue data
$queue->enqueue($_) while <$file1>;
# end the queue
$queue->enqueue((undef) x NUM_THREADS); # $queue->end in never versions

# wait for threads to complete
$_->join for @threads;

sub worker {
  while(defined(my $_ = $queue->dequeue)) {
    my ($id, @indices) = split;
    print $id, map $file2[$_][$indices[$_]], 0 .. $#indices;
  }
}
```

Note that this copies the `@file2` into all threads. Fun fact: for the example data, this threaded solution takes roughly 4× as long. This is mostly the overhead of thread creation, so this will be less of an issue for your data.

In any case, *profile* your code to see *where* you can optimize most effectively. I recommend the excellent [`Devel::NYTProf`](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aNYTProf). E.g. for my non-threaded test run with this very limited data, the overhead implied by `autodie` and friends used more time than doing the actual processing. For you, the most expensive line would probably be

```
  print $id, map $file2[$_][$indices[$_]], 0 .. $#indices;
```

but there isn't much we can do here inside Perl.